# Is there a child credit refund for tax year 2022, or is it just a reduction in tax liability? (IRS 1040)

Tags: united-states, income-tax-refund, tax-credit

My tax software didn't show a refund for child credits on my IRS 1040 for tax year 2022 as it did in previous years. I paid foreign taxes and still the balance shows as zero instead of a refund.

I asked support if I did something incorrect and they replied the following (below). Is it true what they write that one will not be getting a refund for that tax year and the child credit only goes against any tax liability for that year?

> "There have been changes to the child tax credit in 2022. This credit
> is no longer refundable and is only applied to your tax liability on
> the return. You can see where the 8094 for the CTC was applied on Line
> 19 of your 1040 form."

Comment: See [relevant "What's New" item in the 1040 instructions](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i1040gi#en_US_2022_publink100081663) and [Schedule 8812](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i1040s8#en_US_2022_publink100061886)

Answer (score 5):

This is somewhat correct. The Child Tax Credit reverted back in 2022, so it's now only partially refundable. Up to $1,500, if you qualify, can be refundable, and is based on earned income.

There are also a couple of exceptions for the "Additional Child Tax Credit", but if you had foreign earned income and filed Form 2555, you are unable to claim that credit.

Comment: To be clear, ACTC (the 'additional' CTC) is the part that is refundable in normal years, excepting 2021 when Rescue Plan made 'base' CTC temporarily refundable (and half paid in _advance_ if they had your data on file) but only if resident in US or PR, which someone filing 2555 probably wasn't. And foreign tax credit is nonrefundable in all years.